Robot framework- GUI Automation-Attaching Certificates and private key to connect to MTLS server
Is there a method to attach a certificate to a Linux environment for GUI login validation in an MTLS setup using Robot framework?
My REST API calls are successful using the 'Create client cert session' keyword, I'm encountering a 400 error during GUI login validation. Seeking guidance on configuring the certificate and private key within the Linux environment to resolve this issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried attaching the certificates via profiles.json and adding it to /usr/lib/firefox/distribution/
Also copied the certificates to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and using command update-ca-certificates.

Code:
    # Solution 1- Adding certificates to policies.json and add it to the firefox folers

    Create Directory    /etc/firefox/policies
    Copy File    ${RESOURCES_DIR}/certificate/policies.json    /etc/firefox/policies/

    Copy File    ${RESOURCES_DIR}/certificate/policies.json    /usr/lib/firefox/distribution/


    # Solution 2- Adding certificates to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and update-ca-cert

    Create Directory    /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
    Copy File    ${RESOURCES_DIR}/certificate/tls-tester.crt    /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
    Copy File    ${RESOURCES_DIR}/certificate/tls-tester.key    /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
    ${files2}    List Directory    /usr/local/share/ca-certificates    absolute=${True}
    Log    ${files2}

    ${result} =    Run Process    command=update-ca-certificates
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${result.rc}    0 

    Close All Browsers

    Open Browser    ${loginURL}    firefox
    sleep    1s
    CaptureScreenshot    ${logFilePath} 


Its not possible to help without looking at your code. Please check guidelines for How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
